# git-bash: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: windows, vue.js, visual-studio-code, git-bash, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set up debugging with vscode on a nuxt project using:

```
https://medium.com/@justin.ramel/nuxt-js-debugging-in-visual-studio-code-822ff9d51c77
```

I've gotten as far as :

```
$ npm run dev-debug

> nuxt4@1.0.0 dev-debug E:\ENVS\js\nuxt4
> node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/6f869cb6-7166-4182-b841-a528917d88fd
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
E:\ENVS\js\nuxt4\node_modules\.bin\nuxt:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt4@1.0.0 dev-debug: `node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt4@1.0.0 dev-debug script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The entire nuxt file is :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
"$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../nuxt/bin/nuxt.js" "$@"
ret=$?
else 
node  "$basedir/../nuxt/bin/nuxt.js" "$@"
ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Edit:

I tried making the changes and got:

```
> node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/458bafd6-1d8c-4a2b-8ec2-5ddc8b4f0fda
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
E:\ENVS\js\nuxt4\node_modules\.bin\nuxt:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {   #!/bin/sh
                                                                ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt4@1.0.0 dev-debug: `node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt4@1.0.0 dev-debug script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 9):

I have a partial explanation and a fix that should work for some people.

### The cause

The root cause of the problem is that `node` got a Bash or Windows shell script as an argument. If you look into the files in `.bin` such as `node_modules\.bin\nuxt`, you will realize that these are actually shell scripts which are supposed to return the real path to the JavaScript file which is supposed to be passed to `node` as an argument.

I don't know how this is even supposed to work under Linux, but I've had this problem happen when using `git-bash` while using the same codebase on a Linux VM worked just fine, so it's definitely environment-specific. If anyone has the answer to this, I'll be happy to add it to the question.

### The solution

Do not pass the file in `.bin` to `node`. Instead find the path to the real file and pass that instead. In this case, it's `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` and many libraries follow the same principle, but it can be a bit tricky to find sometimes, for example `Angular` was in `node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng` on my system.

### A word of caution

This solution bypasses the way the `JavaScript` files are located and may stop working after an update of a library. Or it may not work on all systems. I'm not a `node` developer and only found it while trying to run someone else's code. It was a good enough solution for my use case, but may not be good for you.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was using the wrong path in my package.json:

It didn't work when I had it like this:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bind/nuxt,
  ...
}
```

However it did work when I changed to the correct path:

```
"dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js",
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using below configuration in **package.json** file

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/cross-env API_HOST=url ember serve",
}
```

The above config work for the Linux machine. But I have a windows machine and during **npm run test** I got this error.

In my case when I removed **node --inspect** than its work for me.

```json
"test": "node_modules/.bin/cross-env API_HOST=url ember serve",
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure whether this is the problem, but still try this. Like i have encountered some weird errors in the past while using legacy backticks **``**.

Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked **`...`**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case $(uname) in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=$(cygpath -w "$basedir");;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
"$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../nuxt/bin/nuxt.js" "$@"
ret=$?
else 
node  "$basedir/../nuxt/bin/nuxt.js" "$@"
ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked like this

```
"dev-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js",
```

The reason of why I'm using this approach it's because of this open issue [#8730](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8730) with Nuxt. Source maps are not being used by the VsCode native debugger (on Nuxt Server Side / Static Generator || Universal App).

If your Nuxt App is an SPA, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well while fixing so that our react project can run two different tsconfig files. Note that the "Original" worked locally but failed in our azure pipeline. Both "Fix" and "Original" work both locally and in our pipeline.

Error:

```
> client-app@0.1.0 automation
> ts-node --project src/tests/tsconfig.commonjs.json ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js src/tests/features/**/*.feature --require-module ts-node/register --require src/tests/test.setup.ts --require src/tests/step-definitions/**/*.spec.ts

D:\a\1\s\client-app\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (D:\a\1\s\client-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at phase4 (D:\a\1\s\client-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:649:14)
    at bootstrap (D:\a\1\s\client-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:95:10)
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

Original node script (npm run automation):

```
"automation": "ts-node --project src/tests/tsconfig.commonjs.json ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js src/tests/features/**/*.feature --require-module ts-node/register --require src/tests/test.setup.ts --require src/tests/step-definitions/**/*.spec.ts",
```

Fix:

```
"automation": "ts-node --project src/tests/tsconfig.commonjs.json ./node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js src/tests/features/**/*.feature --require-module ts-node/register --require src/tests/test.setup.ts --require src/tests/step-definitions/**/*.spec.ts",
```

Like others have mentioned. Its a matter of setting the correct pathway to the package file. Cucumber was the issue in my case.